# Euro coins and notes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, kolmogorov-complexity

As the majority of nations using the Euro have the  `,` as the decimal separator, you must use it also.

The task is to output all the values of the Euro coins and notes in ascending order. You must also put the trailing `,00` on the integer values.

`0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00`

I accept both output to stdout or a function returning an array/list. If output is to stdout, the acceptable separators between values are: space, tab, or newline.

There will be no accepted answer, unless I see some one I find very creative.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so I want to know shortest answer by language.

## Update:

Leading `0` zeros are not acceptable. Sorry, I should make it clear before.

## Update 2:

It is also acceptable a function returning a string.

Comment: can there be a trailing space?

Comment: @dzaima: yes. :)

Comment: Are leading zeros acceptable (like `000,01` etc.)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan: no.

Comment: Can I output the values in random order?

Comment: Is a function returning a string OK?

Comment: @scottinet: No. And that would be not fair to previous repondents.

Comment: @nwellnhof: I have to think a little bit more before I answer your question. BTW, what language will you use? Isn't it more byte-economic to implement as output to stdout or function returning a list of values?

Comment: @nwellnhof: I changed the rules a bit in **Update 2** to "It is also acceptable a function returning a string.", due to a C++ answer I liked, that works the way you describe.

Comment: [The accepted answer is the answer that wins the challenge.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8712/12012) You can either accept the shortest answer or no answer at all, but not an arbitrary one.

Comment: Would it not be in better form to have the items in your list also not feature the leading 0x30s?  I'm suggesting that in an edit; you can evaluate it for aesthetics if you have not already done so.

Comment: Can we assume we have a `Locale` set which uses commas for currencies by default (like Dutch or French)? Or should we assume a `US Locale` is set by default, and change it to French manually?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: See Dennis' answer for reference: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141484/29325

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Pure Bash, 48

```bash
s={1,2,5}
eval echo 0,0$s 0,${s}0 ${s}{,0,00},00
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9i22lDHSMe0liu1LDFHITU5I1/BQMdApRhIqlQX1xoogMhqHaCYQS0Q//8PAA).

Comment: Well played! You got the check mark!

Comment: I never noticed the pattern... and I've been using the currency over 15 years..

Comment: @StephanBijzitter many currencies work like that.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```
5Æ#}ì ®eX-2 x2 d".,"
c
```

Returns an array of strings.

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NcYjfewgrmVYLTIgeDIgZCIuLCIKYw==&input=LVI=) with the `-R` flag to output array items on separate lines.

Comment: Go multiline for [22 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NcYjfewgrmVYLTIgeDIgZCIuLCIKYw==&input=LVI=).

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes

```python
print[('%.2f'%(10**(x/3-2)*(5>>~x%3))).replace(*'.,')for x in range(15)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr3gRd6Usla5@JDpIaAmxiniwS1@3mfK2O5MZo9REbQfBlYmCg16lhL7Y2aCEzbmvc4uIqoby@DOAFGoSGHNlnSVi1dMVQG94jPED)

The expression `5>>~x%3` maps the non-negative integers to `1`, `2`, `5`, `1`, `2`, `5`…

It works because `5`, `2`, `1` are the successive right-bitshifts of `5` (`0b101` → `0b10` → `0b1`); we cycle through them backwards.

Answer (score 6):

## [SOGLOnline](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline) offline, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
252¹5∙īυ;{⁴Ζ.,ŗP*F⁾?½
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MjUyJUI5NSV1MjIxOSV1MDEyQiV1MDNDNSUzQiU3QiV1MjA3NCV1MDM5Ni4lMkMldTAxNTdQKkYldTIwN0UlM0YlQkQ_)

The online link doesn't show trailing zeroes, but the offline version does as Javas BigDecimals are nice.

Explanation:

```
252¹5∙īυ;{⁴Ζ.,ŗP*F⁾?½
252¹                 push the array [2, 5, 2]
    5∙               multiply vertically by 5
      īυ;            push 0.01 below that - the main number
         {           iterate over that array - [2,5,2,2,5,2,2,5,2,2,5,2,2,5,2]
          ⁴            duplicate the main number
           Ζ.,ŗ        replace "." with ","
               P       output in a new line
                *      multiply the main number with the current item of the array
                 F⁾?   if the current array item-2 isn't 0, then
                    ½    divide by 2
```

TO run in the offline interpreter, download [SOGLOnlines repository](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), go to compiler/interpreter, open any of the `.pde` files with [Processing](http://processing.org/), then do file -> export for your OS (otherwise you can't give arguments to a Processing program :/), and then execute the compiled program with an argument to the path of the file with the code. Then, stdout will contain [this](https://pastebin.com/Jy1u2vkQ).

[`2L¼2¹5∙īυ;{⁴Ζ.,ŗP*`](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MkwlQkMyJUI5NSV1MjIxOSV1MDEyQiV1MDNDNSUzQiU3QiV1MjA3NCV1MDM5Ni4lMkMldTAxNTdQKg__) for 18 bytes almost works but the zero amount grows, resulting in `0,01 0,02 0,050 0,100 0,200 0,5000 1,0000 2,0000 5,00000 10,00000 20,00000 50,000000 100,000000 200,000000 500,0000000` (newlines replaced with spaces)

Comment: Output format incorrect: "You must also put the trailing `,00` on the integer values." (I imagine this is also intended to include the trailing `,0` where appropriate)

Comment: You should fix your post according to @JonathanAllan 's observation. JonathanAllan, thanks

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Hmmmpf, let me take your comment with a grain of salt. Post author says: "*The online link doesn't show trailing zeroes, but the offline version does as Javas BigDecimals are nice.*". So I have no way to check whether the script behaves well or not on the offline version.

Comment: @sergiol Ah, I missed that text. I wonder why the online interpreter is implemented differently in this regard - dzaima...?

Comment: I believe the [online interpreter](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline) is written in JavaScript while the [offline one](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL) is written in Processing. Also solutions don't *have* to be testable online. :P

Comment: @JonathanAllan The Java version uses Javas BigDecimals for numbers, while the Javascript version uses my modified version of some Bigs. It's not that easy that easy to port a whole javas library :p

Comment: I didn't realise you needed to write a whole other interpreter to have it work online (I guess there is a problem with running the Processing version online?) Yeah not easy to port something like that!

Comment: @totallyhuman I realise they don't have to be testable online, that was just me not reading everything!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Processing.js did most of the work converting Processing to Javascript, but a couple things (e.g. BigDecimal) it doesn't implement.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>109</s> <s>108</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

Thanks to @OlivierGrégoire for the Locale idea

```java
x->{for(double i=.001;i<11;)System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f ",i*=10,i*2,5*i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xasMwFEV3f8UjUJBDIuxAJ8VZ0pYOpYVm6FA6KLIUnitLRnoKLcHf7go30C53OFwu53byLNd@0K5rPyfsBx8Iusx4IrT8yStptSiUlTHCG1wKgEiSUP0rmeQUoXd8711MvQ7bl2OnFe0gQDN9rXcX4wNrfTpaDdjwqqoFbutalIfvSLrnPhEfAjoybHHDNwb@YrHCZVNXOTer2yWWYpxEdhjyVna4qpw9ttBLdOxAeeb0/iHLWRXg9wCPmu60kckSu5KH1/vn/WMp5lbgUik9EHPJ2pmNxTj9AA)

Comment: You can save a byte by switching to an unused parameter [(meta post on this)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/69583): [Try it online](https://tio.run/##RU7LasMwEPwVIShIxlniQE@Oc@kH9JBDDqWHjSyXdWRJSKuQYvLtrgqFMjAMDPOY8Y67EK2fx9tmHOYsLmtmZDJirh4UJgdT8YYpeHgLPpfFpuP7dbaGT2nYHrvTOoWkxlCuzgoaYN/1dOx@uRm6vT5/Z7YLhMIQE3lWUkINLFjVCxwm8U@ypZaaQ/vakIZko0NjlQTZVmjdP7c@1pF67e/hPdAoFiSvzlyrvz4@Ua8J0BgbWfniXA09tx8)

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY6xagMxDIb3PIU4ODhTxziFLnWbpXPpkLF0cBxf8NVnm5McCOGWPE@fqi9ycU0qDf/PL/FJgz7pdUw2DIfvJeW9dwaM14jwrl2AywrgniJpKnKK7gBjmXU7mlw4fn6Bno7I6irAUHgik/Oiz8GQi0G8xYB5tNPLx36whrbwe/2B10Wvt5c@TncM4HMjuWwRlOQtSlAtcllF/ms1jcDkHXWNahjbnZHsKGImkQqF@g4fSvMNf@RPTM0L1FL1tXJWaGNsoi5k79lfOq/m5QY).

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY6xasMwFEV/RQQKsnEecaCT4yxpQofSQjN0KB0U@Sk8V5aM9BRaTL7dVaGQoctZLvee26uLWvoRXd99ztqqGMXbFFkxadHnDBKTBZOcZvIOdt7FNGDYvJx61LwN7fy13E7GB9n5dLIoqIVV3dCm/mXZ1qvi@B0ZB/CJYQzk2MjFHayNuGFRUUXlurovqWiuczPmpez/u3Hx1IlBkZNHzv3z@4cqptu3J6@VRYjID2hUsiz/ZYfX/fPusWgCKK1xZOmStdl0nX8A). Works on my system because my default locale is be_FR. "Work on my system" is good enough. I can't find the meta-post linked to this, but you can use it. To simulate it, just have `Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);` in the non-competite part of the TIO.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire [Here is the relevant meta-post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/should-locale-be-explicitly-specified/7886#7886), and you're indeed right that it is allowed. I even asked OP to verify, and he linked me to _Dennis_' answer with a link to this meta post.

Comment: 80 bytes: `x->{for(double i=.001;i<11;)System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f ",i*=10,i*2,5*i);}`

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
ＥＥ×125⁵⁺⁺×0⁻²÷κ³ι×0÷κ³⁺⁺✂ι⁰±²¦¹,✂ι±²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sQCMQzJzU4s1lAyNTJV0FEw1dRQCckqLNcAEVMoAKOGbmQcUMNJR8Mwrccksy0xJ1cjWUTDW1ARqyNRRQFKJoQDFyOCczORUDaAOAx0Fv9T0xJJUDSOgAkMgVtJRApJwBXBZELD@//@/btl/3eIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   125                                  String `125`
  ×   ⁵                                 Repeated 5 times
 Ｅ                                      Map over each character
              ÷κ³   ÷κ³                 Integer divide loop index by 3
            ⁻²                          Subtract from 2
          ×0      ×0                    Repeat the string `0` x times
        ⁺⁺       ι                      Concatenate with the character
Ｅ                                       Map over each resulting string
                         ✂ι⁰±²¦¹        Slice off the last two digits
                                ✂ι±²    Extract the last two digits
                       ⁺⁺       ,       Concatenate with a comma
                                        Implicitly print one per line
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

Complete program. Outputs to space-separated to STDOUT.

```apl
'\.'⎕R','⊢2⍕×\.01,14⍴2 2.5 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdtbQov/i/eoye@qO@qUHqOuqPuhYZPeqdenh6jJ6BoY6hyaPeLUYKRnqmCkYg5f/B6gE)

`2 2.5 2` the list;
 `[2,2.5,2]`

`14⍴` cyclically **r**eshape to length 14;
 `[2,2.5,2,2,2.5,2,2,2.5,2,2,2.5,2,2,2.5]`

`.01` prepend 0.01;
 `[0.01,2,2.5,2,2,2.5,2,2,2.5,2,2,2.5,2,2,2.5]`

`×\` cumulative multiplication;
 `[0.01,0.02,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500]`

`2⍕` format with two decimals;
 `" 0.01 0.02 0.05 0.10 0.20 0.50 1.00 2.00 5.00 10.00 20.00 50.00 100.00 200.00 500.00"`

`⊢` yield that (to separate `','` from `2`)

`'\.'⎕R','` PCRE **R**eplace periods with commas;
 `" 0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00"`

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 38 bytes

```bash
printf %.2f\\n {1,2,5}e{-2..2}|sort -h
```

Requires an appropriate locale, [which is allowed by default and costs no bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7886/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvjv4@jnbpuaF@/i/b@gKDOvJE1BVc8oLSYmT6HaUMdIx7Q2tVrXSE/PqLamOL@oREE34/9/AA)

Comment: The output is not respecting ascending order!

Comment: I broke it when I switched from newlines to spaces to save a byte. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

## R <s>70</s>, 50 bytes

inspired by @Giuseppe:

```
format(c(1,2,5)*10^rep(-2:2,e=3),ns=2,de=",",sc=F)
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/KDexRCNZw1DHSMdUU8vQIK4otUBD18jKSCfV1lhTJ6/Y1kgnJdVWSUdJpzjZ1k3z/38A)

Ungolfed

```
format(c(1,2,5)*10^rep(-2:2, each = 3),
   nsmall = 2, 
   decimal.mark = ",",
   scientific = FALSE)
```

Comment: I could only manage 56 using a similar method, just with an t(outer()) rather than the rep(). Not sure if we're allowed that leading whitespace though, that'd cost 4 bytes to fix.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> <s>77</s> <s>75</s> 73 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*
*-1 byte thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer*
*-2 bytes thanks to @totallyhuman*
*-2 bytes thanks to @Lynn*

```python
print[('%.2f'%(v*m)).replace(*'.,')for m in.01,.1,1,10,100for v in 1,2,5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kWkNdVc8oTV1Vo0wrV1NTryi1ICcxOVVDS11PR10zLb9IIVchM0/PwFBHz1AHCA2AyAAkXAYUVjDUMdIxjf3/HwA)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer *forgets to remove spaces*

Comment: I forgot to specify what kind of separator between values are acceptable. Don't worry, newline is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 37 bytes

```
smmX%"%.2f"*dk\.\,[1 2 5)[.01.1 1T^T2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzg3N0JVSVXPKE1JKyU7Ri9GJ9pQwUjBVDNaz8BQz1DBMCQuxOj/fwA)

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 37 bytes

Will shorten in a few minutes.

```
V[.01.1 1T^T2)V[1 2 5)X%"%.2f"*NH\.\,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyxaz8BQz1DBMCQuxEgzLNpQwUjBVDNCVUlVzyhNScvPI0YvRuf/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

Returns an array.

```
_=>[...'125'.repeat(k=5)].map(c=>(c*(c-1?k:k*=10)/5e3).toFixed(2).split`.`.join`,`)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f = 

_=>[...'125'.repeat(k=5)].map(c=>(c*(c-1?k:k*=10)/5e3).toFixed(2).split`.`.join`,`)

console.log(f())
```

---

## Recursive version (ES7), 84 bytes

Returns a string with a trailing space.

```js
f=(i=0)=>i<15?('125'[i%3]/100*10**(i/3|0)).toFixed(2).split`.`.join`,`+' '+f(i+1):''
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(i=0)=>i<15?('125'[i%3]/100*10**(i/3|0)).toFixed(2).split`.`.join`,`+' '+f(i+1):''

console.log(f())
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 42 bytes

```
5$*0
0
$'1$`¶$'2$`¶$'5$`¶
..¶
,$&
m`^00?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy1RFy4DLgEtF3VAl4dA2FXUjCGUKorj09ICEjooaV25CnIGBPdf//wA) Explanation: There are fifteen values, with 1, 2 and 5 in each of five places. The first stage inserts five 0s. The second stage repeats them into a square, then changes the trailing diagonal into 1s, then duplicates those lines three times with 2 and 5. The third stage inserts the commas and the last stage removes unnecessary leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
”{➙∧N\`�4✳×″↶tι⦄|Ｑ~(↥↗⁻“Ｑ§U‴w⎇δUη◨÷¤Ｇ”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJQMfAUAFIGIEIUyBhaAAkjECEqYGCoY6BgYIRiDAFEYYGYD6YNDWAiECFoGIgSknz////umX/dYtzAA) Link is to verbose version.

Yay, compression!

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 88 bytes

```bash
s=125
for i in {0..14};{ printf %1.2f\  `bc<<<"scale=2;${s:i%3:1}*10^$[i/3-2]"`|tr . ,;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9jW0MiUKy2/SCFTITNPodpAT8/QpNa6WqGgKDOvJE1B1VDPKC1GQSEhKdnGxkapODkxJ9XWyFqlutgqU9XYyrBWy9AgTiU6U99Y1yhWKaGmpEhBT0HHuvb/fwA)

Comment: After all that hard work, `echo 0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00` is the same length :(

Comment: @DigitalTrauma But that's no fun :P

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>138</s> 120 bytes

-18 bytes thanks to MSalters

```cpp
#include<iostream>
void p(){for(auto&a:{"0,0%d ","0,%d0 ","%d,00 ","%d0,00 ","%d00,00 "})for(int b:{1,2,5})printf(a,b);}
```

**Hardcoded version, by Lynn, 116 bytes**

```cpp
#include<ios>
void p(){puts("0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00");}
```

Comment: You should include some online example for people seeing it running. I already did it for you: https://tio.run/##RczBCgIhFIXhvU8hE4bCDSxoMza9i6NjCM0o5rgRn920gnbfvzhHeX96KFXrwW7quevlZt0rhkWudyT36HCa8hkucC3ik2bKAwdONB6ggWjeQTTwH/hfXxaRnNXYU5aNC7S/HOVoWA@7RTyPifnQZKiEmYlSV2k3ylBGbSNQqW8

Comment: No need for `v` and `f`: `void p(){for(auto&a:{"0,0%d ","0,%d0 ","%d,00 ","%d0,00 ","%d00,00 "})for(int b:{1,2,5})printf(a,b);}` - just 120 bytes

Comment: `#include<ios>␤void p(){puts("0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00");}` is 116 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes

Returns an array.

```
_=>[...Array(13),b=.005,i=0].map(p=>(b*=++i%3?2:2.5).toFixed(2).replace(".",","))
```

#### Demo

```js
let f = 

_=>[...Array(13),b=.005,i=0].map(p=>(b*=++i%3?2:2.5).toFixed(2).replace(".",","))

console.log(f())
```

---

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>70</s> 61 bytes

```r
options(scipen=9,OutDec=",")
print(c(1,2,5)*10^rep(-2:2,e=3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7@gJDM/r1ijODmzIDXP1lLHv7TEJTXZVklHSZOroCgzr0QjWcNQx0jHVFPL0CCuKLVAQ9fIykgn1dZYU/P/fwA)

*-9 bytes thanks to Rui Barradas*

Outgolfed by [AndriusZ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141464/67312)

Comment: I think there are no 1000€, 2000€ and 5000€

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by removing `print`

Comment: by mixing your and my answers we can achieve 50 bytes - `format(c(1,2,5)*10^rep(-2:2,e=3),ns=2,de=",",sc=9)`

Comment: @AndriusZ I think you still need a `print` around that answer but you should post it yourself; I just used the most barbaric method to change the settings, using `format` required some actual thought.

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by combining the two `options` into one. `options(OutDec=",",scipen=5)`.

Comment: @AndriusZ: No there aren't. So Giuseppes's answer is not valid.

Comment: @sergiol fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 95 bytes

```
(dotimes(i 5)(dolist(j'(1 2 5))(princ(substitute #\, #\.(format()"~$ "(*(expt 10(- i 2))j))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhLCoAwEMWuMqjgG1FRwdu48VNhxE@xU3Dl1WsxkEUy7@JsCFgulcM4CPUcI17FlqOlLg6GveWc4fzkVNSroXQoozXW6z5GBSdvRgkKmMcqtQ0qEuqYN/4J4QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 28 bytes

```
ṁm↔ṪöJ',CtN`J§¤eR'0≥≤2ḣ5"125
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9odXNr///huYFt4oaU4bmqw7ZKJyxDdE5gSsKnwqRlUicw4oml4omkMuG4ozUiMTI1//8)

Just string manipulation, since Husk is terrible at formatting floating point numbers.

### Explanation

```
ṁm↔ṪöJ',CtN`J§¤eR'0≥≤2ḣ5"125
                        "125  The string "125".
                      ḣ5      The range [1,2,3,4,5].
   Ṫö                         Compute their outer product wrt this function:
                               Arguments are number n (say 3) and character c (say '5').
             §     ≥≤2         Compute max(0,n-2+1) and max(0,2-n+1),
                R'0            repeat '0' those numbers of times,
              ¤e               and put them into a list: ["00",""]
           `J                  Join with c: "005"
        CtN                    Split to lengths 2 and at most 3: ["00","5"]
     J',                       Join with ',': "00,5"
                              This gives a 2D array of the outputs reversed.
ṁ                             Map and concatenate
 m↔                           map reversal.
                              Implicitly print separated by newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```c
p(n){printf("%d,%02d ",n/100,n%100);}f(n){for(n=1;n<5e4;n*=10)p(n),p(n*2),p(n*5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79AI0@zuqAoM68kTUNJNUVH1cAoRUFJJ0/f0MBAJ08VSGpa16aBFKXlF2nk2Rpa59mYpppY52nZGhpognTrAAktIwhlClT8PzcxM08DqF4DxAEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
125S5иεN3÷°*т/'.',:N2›i0«
```

Returns a list of strings.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//zEyNVM10LjOtU4zw7fCsCrRgi8nLicsOk4y4oC6aTDCq///)

**Explanation:**

```python
125                          # Push 125
   S                         # Split to a list of digits: [1,2,5]
    5и                       # Repeat it 5 times: [1,2,5,1,2,5,1,2,5,1,2,5,1,2,5]
      ε                      # Map each to:
       N3÷                   #  Integer-divide the map-index by 3
          °                  #  Take it to the power 10
           *                 #  Multiply the current map number with it
            т/               #  Divide it by 100
              '.',:          #  Replace all "." with ","
                   N2›i      #  And if the map-index is larger than 2:
                       0«    #   Append a "0"
```

`125S5и` could be `•}•15∍` (push compressed `125`; enlarge it to size 15: `125125125125125`) and `'.',:` could be `` „.,`: `` (push string ".,", pop and push the characters as separated items to the stack) for the same byte-count: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiWiA2NH3U0Xtuq5/x4e2HNmhdbNJ/1DBPTyfBys/oUcOuTINDq///BwA)
Also, `N3÷°*т/` can be shortened to `N3÷Í°*` (where `Í` subtracts 2), but unfortunately we need the `/` so all the numbers becomes decimals, whereas with `N3÷Í°*` most numbers will remain integers.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 104 bytes

```
SELECT FORMAT(p*n,'0\,00')
FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(5))a(n),(VALUES(1),(10),(100),(1E3),(1E4))b(p)
ORDER BY p,n
```

Line breaks are for readability only.

Annoyingly longer than the trivial `PRINT` version (90 bytes):

```
PRINT'0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00'
```

Comment: You can append to your answer an online demo: https://rextester.com/IBKO53221

Comment: And remove the newlines for it to be more golfy: https://rextester.com/ZANC22480

Answer (score 0):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 41 bytes

```
00000000: 1dc5 8105 0040 1402 d055 1ae0 50d1 feab  .....@...U..P...
00000010: dd2f 788f 8fc2 e192 433c 5c42 e891 7049  ./x.....C<\B..pI
00000020: 11ab 67a6 b8bc 90f5 01                   ..g......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc49DsIwDAXgnVO8Exg7TdoEMSCY2FjYWJq/LiCxVOL2wS3deJJlefn84hzjs0zzqzXecoDk5OCFHZgtQywbZHYOMhaG4yyoZYwALTnp3IluunY/QdTI2VQM3lf4mgyKBAPbdQkuWT19EAxsgxr7z8pcjo8z0fu6GWbpIfqkH8Ye0ceEwFUbCf5DNK0GtfYF)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 58 bytes

```
¶0¶00¶000¶0000¶
.*¶
1$&2$&5$&
^
¶
+`¶(.?.?¶)
¶0$1
..¶
,$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@f69A2AyACYwgBJLn0tICEoYqakYqaqYoaVxxQFZd2wqFtGnr2evaHtmmCdKkYcunpAcV1VNT@/wcA)

Comment: I double-checked with a question to the OP - the leading zeros are not acceptable :(

Comment: You should fix your post according to @JonathanAllan 's observation. JonathanAllan, thanks

Comment: @sergiol fixed it

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>100</s> 99 bytes

### Submission

```
fun g(){var i=1
while(i<1e5){listOf(1,2,5).map{print("%d,%02d ".format(i*it/100,i*it%100))}
i*=10}}
```

### Runner

```
fun g(){var i=1
while(i<1e5){listOf(1,2,5).map{print("%d,%02d ".format(i*it/100,i*it%100))}
i*=10}}

fun main(vararg string: String) {
    g()
}
```

### TryItOnline

[Link](https://tio.run/##HY5BCsMgFET3nuITEDRIqoFsSnOGLnoCIdF@qiYY2y7Es1vT2cxbzZvXlhyGWs07gGU8f3QEnBX5PtGtDG9qnXh2eKS7YUqMYuKD13veI4bEOroIKscFusFs0evEsMd0UVKKE2gDzgvBflayFEJOidcYWLPoaOFIbcZe4fFvDplAS7tBSq0/)

### Edits

-1 | println -> print

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>66</s> 62 bytes

```ruby
-2.upto 2{|m|[1,2,5].map{|v|$><<('%.2f '.%v*10**m).tr(?.,?,)}}
```

4 bytes shorter thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X9dIr7SgJF/BqLomtybaUMdIxzRWLzexoLqmrEbFzsZGQ11VzyhNQV1PtUzL0EBLK1dTr6RIw15Px15Hs7b2/38A)

Comment: `-2.upto 2{…}` saves 3 bytes. `'%.2f '.%v*10**m` saves one byte (calling the `%` method!)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```perl6
{TR/./,/}o{((10 X**^5-2)X*1,2,5).fmt('%.2f')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OiRIX09fR782v1pDw9BAIUJLK85U10gzQstQx0jHVFMvLbdEQ11VzyhNXbP2vzVXcWKlQpqGpvV/AA)

Function returning a string.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, <sub><s>94</s> <s>93</s></sub> 92 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs the euro units to the VBE immediate window.

Restricted to 32-Bit VBA as exponentiation of the form `a^b` throws an error in 64-Bit VBA. To run in 64-Bit, change `10^j` to `10 ^j`.

```vb
For j=-2To 2:For Each i In Array(1,2,5):?Replace(Format(i*10^j,"0.00"),".",",")" ";:Next i,j
```

-1 Byte for replacing `Next:Next` with `Next i,j`

Comment: Extra space in `10 ^j`, isn't it? Can't run, keeps saying "Expected: expression".

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ - its actually a result of a [slight difference](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143645/61846) in exponentiation between 64 bit and 32 Bit VBA - namely that `a^b` throws an error in 64-bit VBA and not 32-Bit; I Just double checked and this runs perfectly without error in the 64-Bit Version. That said, and assuming that this runs fine without the space in 32-Bit VBA, I'll restrict the source and remove the single byte

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 107 bytes

```cs
Console.Write("0,01{0}2{0}5 0,10 0,20 0,50 1{1}2{1}5{1}1{2}2{2}5{2}10{2}20{2}50{2}"," 0,0",",00 ","0,00 ");
```

[Run it](https://tio.run/##HYoxCwMhDIX/SnC6A1sSwenGzp06dBYrRbgqXGyhSH67jR3e971HEvkU65HGeHMuT7h9uaXXFvfADLFzCy1H@NT8gGvIZVn7pRauezrfj9zSYtAidRSn8YCWUOEmPAJ10gOJ11B32p12J4RzTPgJY43@o8oiggr/XjeRMX4)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 96 bytes

```
x=>{for(o="",b=-2;b<3;b++)for(n of[1,2,5])o+=(n*10**b).toFixed(2).replace(".",",")+" ";return o}
```

And here's a slightly longer (98 characters) functional approach:

```
x=>[].concat.apply([],[.01,.1,1,10,100].map(n=>[n,n*2,n*5])).map(n=>n.toFixed(2).replace(".",","))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 36 bytes

```
echo'.,'charsub 0j2":,1 2 5*/~10^i:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19dT0c9OSOxqLg0ScEgy0jJSsdQwUjBVEu/ztAgLtPK6P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 80 bytes

```
lmap d {-2 -1 0 1 2} {lmap c {1 2 5} {puts [regsub \\. [format %.2f $c\e$d] ,]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@V@cWqKQmlem4ePo566pUFASHxDyPyc3sUAhRaFa10hB11DBQMFQwahWoRosmqxQDeQpmAL5BaUlxQrRRanpxaVJCjExegrRaflFuYklCqp6RmkKKskxqSopsQo6sbW1//8DAA)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 90 bytes

```
lmap d {.01 .1 1 10 100} {lmap c {1 2 5} {puts [regsub \\. [format %.2f [expr $c*$d]] ,]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlLCoAgGAav8i1qEyEadBp1YT7aFIkPCMSz/0nMbIYp9iK6bhPh0BgXYAIDPuQd7T8WTWDDPjrWkiGTP3M9oBSDDE@6TcHMtgDp35gw2WVyWmPVvRN9)

Still very long, golfing it more later!

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq/xFbaSkhFYdxVyYWAxkiU4QiGe399hdrWXPIIxqZQoe5Qo2wqHMUFgqSnw5Qyd/5nfHtkno40nBMnqpDmj/xYTOiXkSoiNpDAZTV7pdAlUsrf0

Comment: It occupies the same byte extent as literal: [puts "0,01 0,02 0,05 0,10 0,20 0,50 1,00 2,00 5,00 10,00 20,00 50,00 100,00 200,00 500,00"](https://tio.run/##LcgxCgAgDEPRqxRnh7TQE7k6COr5a6MuL@Sv1iPGXlMKKlQSI54oEiMO0QqIESeK@6@OV376jVMiDg)

Comment: Same byte extent: [`set i -2;time {lmap c {1 2 5} {puts [regsub \\. [format %.2f [expr $c*1e$i]] ,]};incr i} 5`](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq/yFbaKCBFcdxVyUTDGQJTpBIJ7d3hN/tZZJwBj1IhwI5QpbhEeZoWEqSnwlwyY687tjXSfY40lhE3STPmDpiwnK9zMpdg6DqwvfPoErTGs/)

Comment: using `time` to iterate instead of `lmap` renders more bytes: [`set d -3;time {incr d;lmap c {1 2 5} {puts [regsub \\. [format %.2f $c\e$d] ,]}} 5`](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgEATAr2yhnZKIsfIpQKHHaUxECZwV4e04I3S3llngMc6rXIFRrocS/HqHLYJQJmgsFSV@kmESn/nbYa2COd4UNkGv9IGOLHfeYXC1YmntBw)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
5125ß*m{ï3/ú*_♀/\♀%αû,0u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/U0Mj08Hyt3OrD6431D@/Sin80s0E/Bkiontt4eLeOQen//wA)

### Explanation

```
5                          Push 5
 125ß                      Push [1,2,5]
     *                     Multiply
      m{                   Map each element to...
        ï                  Push map index
         3/                Divide by 3
           ú               Push 10**TOS
            *              Multiply           
             _             Duplicate element
              ♀/           Divide by 100
                \♀%        Swap top two elements and calculate TOS % 100
                   α       Wrap last two elements in array
                    û,0    Push ",0"
                       u   Join array with separator
```